# Visio Online Javascript session.init timeout

Tags: office-js, visio

I'm still struggling to get the Visio Online Javascript samples to work - I had though part of the problem was that I didn't have a Visio Online license but that doesn't seem to be the problem now I have a full license

Having slightly modified the sample to add a rejection call back to the session.init promise call I am getting timeout error returned - the visual Visio Online IFrame is created ok

What is causing this ?

Comment: I'd suggest that you update your question to include the code that's resulting in the timeout error. Without it, others won't be able to reproduce and/or troubleshoot your error, and you'll be unlikely to get much help here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Kim thank you for your note - this is the same Visio online API sample  code as other people have commented that they are also getting failures at the session.init point of the script so I did not think it needed regurgitating - what is badly needed are more samples and better error diagnostics to make adoption easier.

Comment: Hi Rupert, I've built a tool that exports working copy of the document with playground, where you can check the javascript - in principle, embedding works. Check out the tool: http://unmanagedvisio.com/using-svgpublish-as-visio-online-script-playground/ The github repository: https://github.com/nbelyh/svgpublish-templates/blob/master/vp-template-visio.html

Comment: Also feel free to contact me personally if you have questions/issues.

Comment: @RupertB, although I understand your point of view, it's best practice for Stack Overflow questions to include all of the information that someone would need to repro/troubleshoot the issue your'e having (including the code that you've tried and a thorough description of the issue you're experiencing with that code). If you post a question without including this type of information, you're not only unlikely to get help here, but your question is more likely to be downvoted/closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example and complete documentation for Visio Online APIs here: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/visio/visio-javascript-reference-overview

Also, there are some more examples in this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visio/2017/09/25/migrate-from-visio-web-access-to-visio-online/. Even though the blog is focused on migration from Visio Web Access, you can checkout the working examples in the 'Embed a Visio drawing in a classic SharePoint page with key properties' section.

Rahul Mittal | Program Manager | Microsoft Visio